# do i need csrf protection for Get requests in Restapi applications?

Tags: rest, security, csrf

I have a RestApi application, where the user send many get requests to the RestApi endpoints and retrieve Json response. The get request includes csrf tokens as a cookie, however , the server does not check the csrf token, i tested it by sending an empty value of the csrf token, and the server answered with 200 ok. 
Is it ok if i don't protect such endpoints Get requests? 
and is there any risk of sending csrf tokens in Get requests to the RestApi endpoints ?

Comment: use it when doing post request. not necessary on get requests

Comment: what about corss site DOS attacks, i read somewhere, that it might be useful to protect against such attacks ?